Space science fiction film showing a man with long blond hair in the fetal position inside a spaceship
I'm trying to track down the name of an animated space science fiction film that I remember seeing on UK television in the late 80s or very early 90s. I am guessing that it was a film made somewhere between the late 70s to mid 80s.
I have only one image in my mind from the film and that is of a man with long blond hair in the fetal position inside a spaceship. A window is behind him (space shown through the glass) and the camera moves away from him.
The art style is what I would think of as more French/European, possibly American. I wouldn't have said it was anime. An art style somewhat like Heavy Metal. I also think from this memory of mine that it was perhaps a more serious type of film, more 2001: A Space Odyssey than Star Wars. Has anyone any ideas as to what this film might be?

I'm going to suggest The Time Masters, Rene Laloux's film from 1982. It was shown on british TV (i suspect re dubbed from French to english)and is well within your timescale and seems to come up as an answer to lots of questions on this site... years since I've seen it so can't comment on there being a scene like you describe... watch the trailer, see if it rings any bells... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D4f4tprXSiA

you might also want to check out episodes of Ulysses 31. Much of the design work was done by Möbius so it has that Heavy Metal vibe to it and the main character has long flowing hair.https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5BSzGfm3oQY&list=PLq_ldxFJLwguNI7Mp2lXh6gCu5Eyx8ivP

ha, i came to say Ulysses 31 too!

Ulysses 31 features 1980s anime-style animation, though, courtesy of Tokyo Movie Shinsha.

It definitely wasn't Ulysses 31, I remember watching that many times back in the day. Time Masters is certainly very close to the art style of the scene I remember, though having flicked through it quickly on YouTube it doesn't have the scene in question. I may be wrong, but I'm pretty sure that's not the film.

You could improve this Story-Identification question by going through the checklists here and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.
